# can any one explain why there can have two verbs for me? what you ate is not stinky tofu in Taiwan

Tags: verbs

I have no idea why there can exit **two verbs** in a one sentence

> what you **ate** **is** not stinky tofu in Taiwan.

Comment: Could you tell us more precisely what you are unsure about? Is it that a verb immediately follows another verb? By the way, you can edit your question by clicking on the `edit` button below.

Comment: Perhaps this might answer your question https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/81925/two-verbs-in-one-sentence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many sentences have more than one verb. This is true in (nearly?) all languages. Second verbs can be in all sorts of subordinate clauses. Here is a sentence with a main verb "met" and a subordinate clause with a verb "lived". The clauses are linked with a connecting word (subordinating conjunction) "where".

> I met her in Paris where I lived as a child.

The order of clauses can be changed. Here the main verb is "went" and the subordinate clause has "ate".

> After we ate lunch, we went to the shops

Sometimes a subordinate clause can function like a noun "What she wanted" is a subordinate clause that is an object of the main verb "gave"

> He gave his mother what she wanted.

Subordinate clauses can also be subjects of sentences.

> What she wanted was a red rose.

Now the subordinate clause "What she wanted" ends with a verb, which is then next to the main verb "was".

And this is the same structure as your sentence

"What you ate" is a subordinate clause, functioning as the grammatical subject. "...is not stinky tofu" is the verb and the complement. It tells us about the subject.